# Convert Enum to String with two digit

Tags: c#, enums

I have a question here in converting an `enum` to a `string`, but I need the conversion to be filled with zero 2 digit.
example

```
public enum System
{
    Unknown = 0,
    Mirror = 3,
    Order = 17
}
```

the output would be this **"03"**.

with example below it works

```
int value;
value = 3;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("D2"));
// Displays 03
```

but with `enum` does not work

```
Console.WriteLine(SourceSystem.Mirror.ToString("D2"));
```

and this error appears

```
System.FormatException 
Message=Format String can be only "G", "g", "X", "x", "F", "f", "D" or "d".....
```

Comment: Cast to int? `int value = (int)System.Mirror; Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("D2"))`

Comment: cast your enum.value to int: ((int) System.Mirror).ToString("D2")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.Mirror` is currently of type enum, so that's why you can't call `ToString("D2")` on it since you need to call this method on a variable of type `int`. So what you should do is first cast the enum to type `int` and then call `ToString("D2")` on that casted variable like so,

```
Console.WriteLine(((int) System.Mirror).ToString("D2"));
```